# Django channels - Echo example not working

Tags: javascript, python, django, websocket, django-channels

I'm following the instructions in the [documentation site](http://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started.html), but I got stuck in the echo example, the websocket is created correctly and it's connected to the server but when I send anything to the server I'm not getting any response (In the example says I should see an alert window with the same message that I send into the socket but I don't, although I've changed the alert for a console.log but still), what I'm doing wrong?

In *settings.py*:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = {
    ...
    'channels',
    'myapp',
    ...
} 

...
# Channels settings
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "asgiref.inmemory.ChannelLayer",
        "ROUTING": "myapp.routing.channel_routing",
    },
}
```

In *routing.py*:

```
from channels.routing import route
from myapp.consumers import *

channel_routing = [
    route("websocket.receive", ws_receive),
]
```

In *consumers.py*:

```
def ws_receive(message):
    # ASGI WebSocket packet-received and send-packet message types
    # both have a "text" key for their textual data.
    message.reply_channel.send({
        "text": message.content['text'],
    })
```

In asgi.py

```
import os
from channels.asgi import get_channel_layer

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.settings")

channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
```

Then I run: python manage.py runserver, and in my browser I go to the server url and in the console I put the following:

```
socket = new WebSocket("ws://" + window.location.host + "/chat/");
socket.onmessage = function(e) {
    alert(e.data);
}
socket.onopen = function() {
    socket.send("hello world");
}
```

Again, at this point I should see an alert window (or the console.log message) but I get nothing.

[image: response]

The requests that I made have a status of pending (Although I read [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189350/websockets-stuck-in-pending-on-stack-overflow) and the first comment says it's normal)

[image: requests]

And the server output looks like this:

[image: server-output]

Every time that I've tried to send something through the websocket in the browser, the server just print CONNECT but no log from the js console is showing.

#### Edit: I've tested websockets in my browser against echo.websocket.org and I got the answer as expected:

[image: test-websocket]

Comment: +1 Having the same issue. The client WebSocket successfully connects to the server and can receive data from the server, but when calling socket.send(), the `ws_receive` consumer method is never called.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I changed to an older version of twisted and it fixed it. Hth

Comment: +1 It did help -- just downgraded to 16.2.0 and it started working as expected. I'll raise this issue on Github.

Comment: It is in fact, the solution. Thank you all! I downgraded Twisted to 16.2.0 and it worked.