# Django channels: Echo example issues

Tags: javascript, python, django, websocket, django-channels

I'm following the sample code provided by the [channels documentation](http://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started.html) and have run into a issue. The django server successfully accepts a websocket from the browser and sending appears to work. However server-side processing of the message (ws_message) does not appear to occur, and no reply (nor any alert) is registered browser-side.

[Sending seems to work, but no reply](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkfW3.png)

This behavior is highly similar to that observed in [Django channels - Echo example not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38237120/solved-django-channels-echo-example-not-working). However while switching to twisted 16.2.0 was the solution to that case, I am already on twisted 16.2.0.

Code snippets are as follows:

*consumers.py*

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from channels.handler import AsgiHandler

def ws_message(message):
    print("sending message ", message.content["text"])
    raise
    message.reply_channel.send({
        "text": message.content["text"]
    })
```

*routing.py*

```
from channels.routing import route
from channel_test.consumers import ws_message

channel_routing = [
    route("websocket.recieve", ws_message),
]
```

*settings.py*

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    "channels",
    "channel_test",
    "argent_display"
]

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default":{
        "BACKEND": "asgiref.inmemory.ChannelLayer",
        "ROUTING": "argent_display.routing.channel_routing"
    }
}
```

The django dev server is then run (manage.py runserver) and the following executed via the browser console:

```
socket = new WebSocket("ws://" + window.location.host + "/chat/");
socket.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log('test');
    alert(e.data);
}
socket.onopen = function() {
    socket.send("hello world");
}
```

Upon receiving a message, an alert should be given and the console logged to. However, neither occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should connect `ws_message` consumer to `websocket.receive` not  `websocket.recieve`.

Comment: And once again, pebkac. Thanks for the assist at catching that.